# including style sheet in a jsp page with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having trouble linking to a style sheet from a jsp page. I believe it has something to do with my directory structure which is:

```
WEB-INF
  |-- css
  |    |-- main.css
  |
  |-- jsp
       |-- login.jsp
```

I have tried various forms of the standard html link tag such as:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="WEB-INF/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I have also tried including the css file in the jsp folder and linking to it directly. Nothing works. When I view the source after deployment, and try to access the CSS file directly, it's not there, but this is no surprise to me since it is in the WEB-INF directory.

I have also verified that it is getting deployed with the rest of the application. The jsp source is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="logout">&nbsp;</div>
<h1>Login</h1>
</div>
<div id="content" class="content">
  <form action="" method="post" name="login-form">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><label>User Name:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="userName" /><br><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Password:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password" /><br><br></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` are not directly public accessible. Only an intermediating (controller) `Servlet` can access and stream them for you with help of [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). That's exactly what Spring (as any other decent MVC framework) does with JSP files. You can't access JSP files directly by URL. That would potentially leak source code or break the application behaviour.

So you have basically 2 options here:

1. Put CSS files in public webcontent (just move one folder above `WEB-INF`, so that `/css` is at same level as `/WEB-INF`).
2. Create a Servlet which listens on an `url-pattern` of `/css/*`, gets the requested CSS file by [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) and basically gets an `InputStream` from it using the aforementioned `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response along a correct set of response headers with at least `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`.

After all I think option 1 is easier and more suitable for your requirement ;)

Comment: I figured that had something to do with it. I believe I will go with option 1 for now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was using twitter bootstrap, and having problem access the assets because I put them under WEB-INF (which is not public, as you mentioned), move it 1 level up to webcontent and access using bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js in my jsp works pretty well.

Answer (score 7):

Spring-style implementation of 2nd approach from @BalusC is to using [mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources), like that:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/*" />
```

and after this your `main.css` file should be available at `/css/main.css`

(NOTE: if it does not work, check that `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/`)

Comment: It does not work as-is for me. I have a mapping /app for my DispatcherServlet (otherwise Tiles is not working with /). In that case a reference to my javascript file will be: <script src='<c:url value="/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"/>'></script>

Comment: @ruffp Yes, AFAIR, `<mvc:resources/>` requires `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to work and thus `DispatcherServlet` should be mapped to `/`

Answer (score -2):

or try this

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

" type="text/css"/>

it may work.

Comment: Casey was asking about using a <link> element to include a stylesheet, so it's not really related to jsp taglibs.