# Sitemesh spring mvc access to the resources in decorator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I have a problem with import css files in decorator.jsp file. My files structure looks following:

```
WEB-INF
    css
        style.css
    decorators
        decorator.jsp
```

How can I access style.css? I tried with different combinations an still didn't get effect.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB-INF/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
```

However contextPath, servletPath, pathInfo always returns null.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have pretty much the same structure as you and the above works...

Comment: I would try moving your css out of WEB-INF, so it isn't under teh control of spring. Move it to the same directory level as WEB-INF and you should be able to access it.

Comment: Actually, looking at my project, my style stuff isn't in WEB-INF. Digging a little deeper on here, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231792/including-style-sheet-in-a-jsp-page-with-spring-mvc) which explains it much better than i do.

Comment: Many thanks! Putting <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> and <mvc:resources ... /> with proper attributes in bean definition resolved this problem.