# Link CSS file to .JSP in Spring Framework - ver -4.1.0

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have visited previous related question to find solution but I didn't...

[How to use "css" in the "jsp" in Spring MVC project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313551/how-to-use-css-in-the-jsp-in-spring-mvc-project)

[including style sheet in a jsp page with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231792/including-style-sheet-in-a-jsp-page-with-spring-mvc)

My question is how do I link css file to .jsp file in Spring MVC, this question was asked by so many of em! but unfortunately couldn't get achieved with those solution.

file structure is- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WKuN.png

Please give your directions, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve that with the following

`<style type="text/css"><%@ include file="/css/bootstrap.css" %> </style>`

where bootstrap.css was my css file and the folder structure was similar. Try that once.

Comment: You mean like this... <style type="text/css"><%@ include file="css/bootstrap.css" %> </style>

Comment: Yes. The css file path you mention in file=... is relative to your WebContent directory. Since you have "css" directory directly under WebContent, the above should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @nagamanojv, when I did <style type="text/css"><%@file="css/bootstrap.css" %> </style> -- server throws an error -- message /WEB-INF/AdmissionForm.jsp (line: 10, column: 27) Invalid directive, I don't know where I am going wrong, thanks for your help

Comment: Its not <style type="text/css"><%@file="css/bootstrap.css" %> </style>.. It is <style type="text/css"><%@ include file="css/bootstrap.css" %> </style>. The server was throwing error because @file is not a valid directive. Please try the one I mentioned. (There should be a space between @ and include. Please mind that)

Comment: When I do like this, <style type="text/css"><%@include file="css/bootstrap.css" %> </style> --  error on the line and when hover on x mark shows -- Fragment "bootstrap.css" was not found at expected path /FirstSpringMVCProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/
  bootstrap.css

Comment: thanks, you are diamond, it worked by doing like this -- <style type="text/css"><%@include file="/css/bootstrap.css" %> </style>, thanks for your help, much appreciated!!!

Comment: could you please look into the question below, now I can't link .js files, please have a look, thanks...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336029/link-jquery-file-with-spring-mvc

Comment: @Java.beginner: I proposed a solution for your problem in the specified link. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

add following line in your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

hope this will help you