# link jQuery file with Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue in linking jQuery file, have placed the .js file under

WebContent

--js

-----toggle.js

file structure is shown in... (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lZpj.png)

Web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class> 
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
      </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.studentadmissioncontroller" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />


       <mvc:annotation-driven/>

      <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
         </property>
        <property name="suffix">
         <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>

      </bean>
```

but .js file is not linked up, please give me a directions, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you please show your web.xml file also

Comment: Sorry @BijuKunjummen for the late reply, have edited the question, thanks for your help...

Comment: I think you just need to add a `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file. This will essentially delegate handling of the static content to the container. Additionally remove the `<mvc:resources` entries, that will also work but with potentially things in your classpath, which it is not in this specific instance.

Comment: Thanks @BijuKunjummen, still it doesn't link with .js file, I can't figure it out, where I am going wrong. Thanks for your directions -

Comment: Any errors, anything on the console, try to get the log level to DEBUG to see what could be going wrong. Spring should show enough information at this log level

Comment: Thanks, on console there is no error, as you said, let me debug it and check the log and will update the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` and you should notice the name (and version ) declare in Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml must same with the file in /js directory (jquery-1.6.2.js,jquery-1.11.1.js, jquery.js v.v...)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

and as everyone suggest, make sure you have

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

in Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

hope it work

Comment: Unbelievable! it worked, Thank you so much @Tung Vo,

Answer (score 0):

Its not a very much spring way, but I could link a javascript file as below

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" ></script>`

Please check if it works for you also.!